# HOSTS file ignores IP addresses on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns, ip

I want to redirect a particular IP address to localhost so I added its IP into hosts file.

But when I ping that IP address it works and doesn't redirect to 127.0.0.1.

But when I add a domain name to the hosts it works (like : 127.0.0.1 google.com).
Tried to do `ipconfig /flushdns` and every solution found on the internet but still having this issue.

It works fine on domains but doesn't work on IP addresses, I'm using Windows 10 64-bit.

Is there some other way to redirect an IP address other than using a router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding in the concept of DNS and the HOSTS file.

When you add an domain name to a HOSTS file, before querying its IP address to a DNS server, the HOSTS file is checked. And if you overwrite the IP address with 127.0.0.1 then the IP address is misleaded and unreachable.

But you can't add an IP address to the HOSTS file becuase it has a `IP-Address Domain.name` syntax. And when you ping an IP address, there is no need of DNS server, because already the IP address is resolved. And it could be reached suucessfully.

To block an IP address, create an outbound firewall rule to block TCP/IP connections to that server.